# How to start exe file cdb.exe and pass argument from process.start

Tags: c#, windbg

If I do the following manually it works fine but I must be able to do the same from C# and in addition be able to close the command window.

1. Open the command window(cmd)
2. use cd to go to the directory where the `cdb.exe` is located which is
   in my case `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86`
3. I do `cdb -z D:\Temp\CrashDump.dmp -logo c:\temp\mydump.text -c "q"`
4. Now there is a `mydump.text`in `c:\temp\`

So I want to do the same from C#. I have tried several solutions. Here is the first one

```
Process.Start(@"program files (x86)\windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe", @"-z D:\Temp\CrashDump.dmp -logo c:\temp\mydump.text -c \\""q\\""");
```

This gives error when executed saying "The system cannot find the specified file.

My second attempt is

```
 Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"program files (x86)\windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe -z D:\Temp\CrashDump.dmp -logo c:\temp\mydump.text -c \\""q\\""");
```

This open the command window but doesn't create the file mydump.text which it should.

I have also tried to add the command to a bat file but it will not work.

The command window should also be closed automatically after the file `mydump.text` has been created.

Comment: In the line `Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"program files (x86)\windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe -z D:\Temp\CrashDump.dmp -logo c:\temp\mydump.text -c \""q\""");` is the part `c:\temp\mydump.text` written with a small c. I thought windows is case sensitive?

Comment: Have you made any log message, so that you could see why it does not create the file `mydump.exe`

Comment: No. windows is not case sensitive. Why don't you start with c:\program files (x86)

Comment: JFYI, You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. While you can accept only one answer, you can upvote as many answer as you find useful, including the accepted one. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
        using (var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"-z D:\Temp\CrashDump.dmp -logo c:\temp\mydump.text -c ""q""";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();    
        }
```